# Unable to parse input string to integer in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game in unity that requires the input of the player for a small calculation.
However, the input number is in a string format and requires to be converted into an integer for calculation. I'm using the **Unity Input Field with TextMesh Pro** for player input.

Here's the method that executes once the "Calculate" button is clicked.
The `CalcObjects` array hold **TextMeshProUGUI's** from the input fields. The second index holds the answer after calculation.

```
public void Calculate()
    {
        string answer = "";

        string velocity = CalcObjects[0].text;
        Debug.Log(Convert.ToInt32(velocity.Trim()));

        CalcObjects[2].text = answer;
    }
```

The error message is:

`FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the input string?

Comment: Rather use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) instead

Comment: It is an integer, the velocity of a wave in this instance

Comment: @SadeemSajid And what is the value of the string when the error happens?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it is 344

Comment: No it is not...

Comment: I would recommend to add `Debug.Log(velocity);` and tell us what exactly it says, and in general start [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code ;)

Comment: @derHugo I did, without any input it Logs as an empty string. if I write the value which is 344, it comes out as "344". I just can't convert it into an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, have to admit that it was rather lazy on my part.

1. I was trying to directly edit the 'text' component of the input fields so instead of using `TextMeshProUGUI's` I should have used `TMP_InputField` variables.
2. Set the content type to `IntegerNumber` as @derHugo suggested, and then used the following code:

```
public void Calculate()
    {
        int answerInt = 0;

        answerInt = Convert.ToInt32(CalcObjects[0].text) / Convert.ToInt32(CalcObjects[1].text);
        Debug.Log(answerInt);
    }
```

Thanks for helping me guys, as you can tell, I'm more of a beginner.

Comment: Congratulations. Now you have three exceptions waiting to happen instead of just one. Both `Convert.ToInt32` will throw `FormatException` when the texts can't be parsed to int values, and that division will throw a `DivideByZeroException if `CalcObjects[1].text` will be `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what exactly the string is you are passing in when you get the error I would rather use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to catch invalid inputs

```
public void Calculate()
{
    var answer = "";

    var velocity = CalcObjects[0].text.Trim();

    if(Int32.TryParse(velocity, out var intValue))
    {
        Debug.Log(intValue);
        CalcObjects[2].text = answer;
    }   
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning($"Invalid input: \"{velocity}\"");
        CalcObjects[2].text = "";
    }
}
```

---

you could btw further avoid any errors already one step before here by setting a specific [`contentType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-contentType.html) for your input field:

```
private void Awake()
{
    CalcObjects[0].contentType = ContentType.IntegerNumber;
}
```

so a user can't even insert anything that is not an integer value

Comment: Yep, thanks for this but the error still persists. No matter what integer value I enter into the input field, it always comes out as an error. In your code, it always comes out to be "Invalid Input"

Comment: could you show exactly what the console prints out in this case?

Comment: in this case, the console does not print out anything, However, "Invalid Input appears in my text box.

Comment: @SadeemSajid no please see the updated answer it should print out exactly what your invalid input was

Comment: Invalid input: "344​"
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)

Sorry, didn't notice the updated code, it prints out this.

Comment: @SadeemSajid hm that sounds really odd tbh ... I don't see why this shouldn't work then. Can you test it once with directly setting `velocity = "344";` via code?

Comment: 344
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

   Now it works...hmm, I'll review my entire code and see if something else is wrong, or maybe something up within the unity editor.

Comment: you do not input additional `"` in the input field right?

Comment: ther _might_ be a possibility of a _non-printable character_ that gets "copy-pasted" or added somehow. You may try to turn the input string as an array of bytes and check unicode / ascii values of each bytes to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue for a few hours fun, turns out TMPro inserts white space characters that will always return a non valid conversion, whether you try Int32.TryParse or not.

The solution is to step through your string and throw out chars that aren't valid digits.

This function works for me, but it assumes the number is positive, and ignores formats, commas etc Use at your own risk, but it got me out of trouble!

```
    public static int IntParseFast(string value)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        char letter = value[i];
        if (letter > 47 && letter < 58) { result = 10 * result + (letter - 48); }
    }
    return result;
}
```